# How to retrieve values from Django query set?

Tags: python, django

I would like to know how to get the values in a template, from a variable called 'my_movie_code_count':

```
my_movie_code_count = Code.objects.values('movie__title').annotate(Count('movie'))
```

If I do a pprint to the console I get:

```
for m in my_movie_code_count:
    pprint.pprint(m)
```

**console output:**

```
{'movie__count': 1, 'movie__title': u'THE MEN WHO STARE AT GOATS'}
{'movie__count': 3, 'movie__title': u'PIRATE RADIO'}
{'movie__count': 1, 'movie__title': u'A SERIOUS MAN'}
{'movie__count': 3, 'movie__title': u'GREENBERG'}
{'movie__count': 1, 'movie__title': u'MILK'}
{'movie__count': 1, 'movie__title': u'TEST'}
```

**template: (Currently it doesn't show any output.)**

```
    {% for movie in my_movie_code_count %}
    {{movie.title}}:{{movie.count}}
    {% endfor %}
```

Comment: I wanted to do something different and just print the whole queryset to console with quickest solution `print(YourModl.objects.all().values())`. Doesn't solve your problem but this was the only related question that came up.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`my_movie_code_count[0].movie__count` now I know this is not exactly wanted so you could add a name to the annotation:

```
my_movie_code_count = Code.objects.values('movie__title').annotate(num=Count('movie'))
print my_movie_code_count[0].num
1
```

you can check the docs here: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#annotate

Also it doesn't shows anything because django fails silently on templates (so a designer doesn't break a whole page). If you check the attributes, their names are `movie__title` and `movie__count` so you would have to change the template attributes to:

```
{{ movie.movie__title }}: {{ movie.movie__count }}
```